# Was there a RCT scenario when you had a compete with a rival park?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

This image has been floating around the web recently:
[image]

As an massive fan of RCT1 and 2 (3 I played a small amount) I don't remember a scenario where you had a rival park. I remember one where your park was split over a highway in RCT2 but nothing described like that above. Was there a park with this mechanic in any of the RCT PC games?

Comment: Remember, RCT also has many expansions, that you might not have played. I've played RCT1 with all expansions and I don't remember a scenario like this. Also, if the game engine supported multiple parks on a map, i think they would have used it in more then a single scenario.

Comment: What about Bullfrog's Theme Park? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_Park_(video_game)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, I've just looked through all the RCT 3  scenarios, and there isn't anything there.  I'm also 99.9% positive (having played RCT1 and 2 for many years!) that there isn't anything in those as default campaigns.

Comment: It is also important to note that based on the RCT engine I highly doubt you would be able to affect another park from your loaded park. Thus this is impossible and this guy is a phoney.

Comment: Or he's just misremembering?  The brain is a strange beast.  I've had mine convince me I did things that, in fact, I only thought about.

Comment: @Kyralessa I think there's been quite a few things on facebook and various websites saying this exact same thing which has made people remember this as a false memory (because it clearly didn't happen!

Answer (score 5):

I highly doubt there was a scenario like this. Programming AI is hard and they would not have spend the time for a single scenario. I can't remember something like this either. And the launching people into the rivals park seems ridiculous, not sure about the mechanics but you would think the dead's get count to the owner of the coaster where they died in.